# How to extend hidden jobs and executes them sequentially in one stage

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

The sample gitlab pipeline is just simplified version of my actual pipeline. But basically I have multiple hidden jobs and I want to run those jobs sequentially in one single stage.

```
.core:job:  
  script:
    - ls    
  
.job1:
  extends:
   - .core:job
  before_script:
   - cd ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/job1


.job2
  extends: 
   - .core:job
  before_script:
   - cd ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/job2
  
# include all the jobs
.job:all: 
  extends:
   - .job1
   - .job2
```

**.gitlab-ci.yml**

```
 stages:  
  - master

 master: 
   stage: master
   extends:
     - .job:all
```

This pipeline is not working, instead of running jobs sequentially it merges only the last job (in this case its job2) and executes only job2

Answer (score 0):

The way to handle this is by using the keyword `needs`, which allows you to execute jobs out-of-order.

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#needs

One thing to keep in mind:

> In GitLab 14.1 and later you can refer to jobs in the same stage as
> the job you are configuring. This feature is enabled on GitLab.com and
> ready for production use. On self-managed GitLab 14.2 and later this
> feature is available by default.

Example:

```yaml
.core:job:  
  script:
    - ls    
  
job1:
  extends:
   - .core:job
  before_script:
   - cd ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/job1


job2:
  extends: 
   - .core:job
  before_script:
   - cd ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/job2
  needs: [ "job1" ]
```

Comment: we are using version 14.10.5 but I get error `undefined need: .job1` One difference from your configuration is my child jobs are hidden and only master job is visible, not sure if that make difference

Comment: looks like you can not use hidden jobs in needs

Comment: In my example I setup job1 and job2 as non hidden jobs. Are you able to use these as non hidden jobs?